# Use a file name as part of a range

Tags: vba, excel, csv, filenames

MS Excel 2010 VBA - teaching myself to automate, have run into a wall.  I'm using VBA to extract raw data from one workbook and plug it into an analysis workbook.
Example - raw data is stored in column G of a sheet in a file named ***something***.csv  I extract the file and sheet names, add a "G" through other steps and I've assigned the file & sheet & G to a variable because the data file name is never the same.  The analysis file contains the macro.

This works fine if the file and sheet name is: "[REPORT.csv]REPORT!"

```
RptName ="[REPORT.csv]REPORT!G"
PulledData = Range(RptName & rawdatarow)
```

But this doesn't work if the file and sheet name is "[873686.0-05.csv]873686.0-05!" or similar.

```
RptName = "[873686.0-05.csv]873686.0-05!G"
PulledData = Range(RptName & rawdatarow)
```

ANY HELP IS GREATLY APPRECIATED!!

Comment: "Doesn't work" can mean many things. Is there any error message? What is the error message?

Comment: Please do not use the [**macros** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) for MS Office / VBA.

Comment: Sorry - the error is Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Answer (score 0):

you need single quotes around references that have mathematical symbos or other special characters, such as spaces.

You would have to alter

```
RptName = "[873686.0-05.csv]873686.0-05!G"
```

to

```
RptName = "'[873686.0-05.csv]873686.0-05'!G"
```

The single quoted version will work even if there are no special characters, so that would be the easiest way to go for all cases, rather than trying to work out where you have to use the quotes